# How to properly add HOST using sails-mongo adapter?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

I've installed [sails-mongo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo) through npm and have a basic [sails.js](http://balderdashy.github.io/sails/) application running 
but it's not recognizing my host.

MongoDB is up and running on the default port 27017 but after I generate a model I get this error when trying to run the application: [image]

Here is my adapter.js, I'm running node v0.10.0 and sails v0.8.895

```
// Configure installed adapters
// If you define an attribute in your model definition, 
// it will override anything from this global config.
module.exports.adapters = {

    // If you leave the adapter config unspecified 
    // in a model definition, 'default' will be used.
    'default': 'mongo',

    // In-memory adapter for DEVELOPMENT ONLY
    // (data is NOT preserved when the server shuts down)
    memory: {
        module: 'sails-dirty',
        inMemory: true
    },

    // Persistent adapter for DEVELOPMENT ONLY
    // (data IS preserved when the server shuts down)
    // PLEASE NOTE: disk adapter not compatible with node v0.10.0 currently 
    //              because of limitations in node-dirty
    //              See https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty/issues/34
    // disk: {
    //  module: 'sails-dirty',
    //  filePath: './.tmp/dirty.db',
    //  inMemory: false
    // },

     mongo: {
        module   : 'sails-mongo',
        url      : 'mongodb://Chris:DBPASSWORD@localhost:27017/localHostTestDB'
      }
};
```

I've already added the user to the localHostTestDB with role of admin.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having to update sails.js to version 0.9.3 and using the sails-mongo adapter as such:

```
module.exports.adapters = {

  // If you leave the adapter config unspecified 
  // in a model definition, 'default' will be used.
  'default': 'mongo',

  mongo: {
    module   : 'sails-mongo',
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'Chris',
    password : 'PASSWORD',
    database : 'localHostTestDB'
  },

  // In-memory adapter for DEVELOPMENT ONLY
  memory: {
    module: 'sails-memory'
  },

  // Persistent adapter for DEVELOPMENT ONLY
  // (data IS preserved when the server shuts down)
  disk: {
    module: 'sails-disk'
  },

  // // MySQL is the world's most popular relational database.
  // // Learn more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL
  // mysql: {
  //   module: 'sails-mysql',
  //   host: 'YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
  //   user: 'YOUR_MYSQL_USER',
  //   password: 'YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD',
  //   database: 'YOUR_MYSQL_DB'
  // }
};
```

Comment: You might want to move the db config to the config/locals.js file. If you are using Git, this file is ignored by gitignore to avoid you publishing your server config. Just add to the module.exports obj:
adapters : {
  'default': 'mongo',
  mongo: {
    module   : 'sails-mongo',
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'Chris',
    password : 'PASSWORD',
    database : 'localHostTestDB'
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Install from NPM.
Add the mongo config to the config/adapters.js file.
visit http://sailsjs.org

Comment: My problem ended up being related to the version of sails even though an issue on github said that the other adapter object could be used. Thanks for your help though!